# validate on array parameter igoners my rules and update

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function that updates the data. It receives the data as an array parameter.

I tried use validator make, and also validate helper method but it didn't work because it's only work for requests, and i tried also in validator make as the code below and also 'params.name' but it didn't work.

```
public function updateCompany(array $params): bool
{
if( Validator::make($params,[
    'name'=> 'required|min:3|unique:company',
    'email'=> 'required|min:4|unique:company|email'
])) {
    return $this->update($params);
    }
}
```

After trying this it didn't give me any error put it ignores my validation rules and update anyway.

Comment: Are you using a POST request? Because then you can use `public function updateCompany(Request $request)`, since you can easily validate requests.

Comment: this is function to update my data my data , this function in a repository and i m calling it in controller

Comment: `Validator::make` just creates the validator, you need to call another method to actually get the validation to happen

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
public function updateCompany(Request $request)
```

then you could do something like this:

```
$rules = array('name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'email|required|unique:users',
        'name' => 'required|min:6|max:20');
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return ['status' => 422, 'errors' => $validator->errors()];

    }
```

Comment: i m using this function in repository and i need to pass the value as array , so i need something work with this case

Comment: If you `dd($params)` what are the results?

Comment: associative array of four